# How to run chrome browser in grid using MAC as hub and Windows as Nod?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-grid

Hub: MAC 64-bit
Nod: Windows 32-bit

Unable to run chrome browser using Selinum grid MAC as hub and Windows as nod?

using below code i am getting an error  (The path to the driver executable must be set by the webdriver.chrome.driver system property; for more information, see http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/ChromeDriver. The latest version can be downloaded from http://code.google.com/p/chromedriver/downloads/list Command duration or timeout: 668 milliseconds)

```
public void chromeWindows() throws MalformedURLException{

System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/Users/vinayakkhatate/Desktop/jar/chromedriver2");
ChromeOptions opt = new ChromeOptions();
opt.setBinary("C:/Users/user/AppData/Local/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe");


DesiredCapabilities capabilies = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
capabilies.setBrowserName("chrome");
capabilies.setPlatform(Platform.VISTA);


driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://10.0.11.118:5566/wd/hub"), capabilies);
driver.get(baseUrl);
System.out.println(driver.getTitle());

driver.close();
driver.quit();

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have solution to run Chrome browser from Mac machine to Windows Vista
(download and save chromedriver in windows vista machine)

Start the hub in Mac with below command

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.33.0.jar -role hub
```

Start the node in windows with below command

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.33.0.jar -role node -hub http://localhost:4444/grid/register -maxSession 15 -browser browserName="chrome",version=ANY,platform=WINDOWS,maxInstances=5 -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=pathtochromedriver\chromedriver.exe
```

Now write code in eclipse in Mac machine

```
DesiredCapabilities capabilies = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
capabilies.setBrowserName("chrome");
capabilies.setPlatform(Platform.ANY);

driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://<ip address of windows machine>:5555/wd/hub"), capabilies);
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually, the chromedriver.exe has to be stored on the Windows node. I do it by creating subfolder `/lib` in my test folder where I store the chromedriver and all other selenium grid related stuff. Later on, when running the node, do it like this:

```
java -jar lib/selenium-server-standalone-2.28.0.jar -role node -hub http://localhost:4444/grid/register -maxSession 15 -browser browserName="chrome",version=ANY,platform=WINDOWS,maxInstances=15 -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=lib\chromedriver.exe
```

especially note the -D switch:

```
-Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=lib\chromedriver.exe
```

Thats how I set up the chromedriver.exe path. Notice the relative path, so I do not have to care really about where in absolute path the tool is running. Hope it helps

**EDIT**
Obviously, the hub and node computers should be acessible by IP. For instance, my work PC has IP `10.131.7.11` in our internal network so if this would be the **hub** computer, then the node setup would be like this:

```
java -jar lib/selenium-server-standalone-2.28.0.jar -role node -hub http://10.131.7.11:4444/grid/register -maxSession 15 -browser browserName="chrome",version=ANY,platform=WINDOWS,maxInstances=15 -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=lib\chromedriver.exe
```

Please note that the localhost changed to IP of the hub. So next steps for you are:

- Set up hub and node to be on same network and being accessible by IP adress
- Run hub on the mac machine
- Run node on the vista, pointing out to the IP adress of the hub
- Cross your fingers :)
- And try running the chrome again

**EDIT2**
This is how I run chrome:

```
  if (System.getProperty("os.name").contains("Windows")) {
        System.setProperty(ChromeDriverService.CHROME_DRIVER_EXE_PROPERTY, "chromedriver.exe");
    } else {
        System.setProperty(ChromeDriverService.CHROME_DRIVER_EXE_PROPERTY, "chromedriver");
    }

  capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
  capabilities.setCapability("chrome.switches", Arrays.asList("--start-maximized"));

  driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub"), capabilities);
```

Comment: Still getting same error.
Please provide me code written in MAC machine to run chrome in VISTA.

Comment: did you change the hub address accordingly? is on the node machine stored chromedriver.exe? The chromedriver needs to be on the node not on the hub

Comment: Yes, i have downloaded chromedriver in windows and setup node using "java -jar lib/selenium-server-standalone-2.28.0.jar -role node -hub http://localhost:4444/grid/register -maxSession 15 -browser browserName="chrome",version=ANY,platform=WINDOWS,maxInstances=15 -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=lib\chromedriver.exe"

Comment: it seems issue is in my code on MAC side, but unable to sort out,

Comment: see the edit. You are running node against localhost - the same machine. That is probably the root cause

Comment: System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/Users/test/chromedriver"); --here i am need to provide chrome driver path of mac right?

Comment: nope. Never ever in the code. The path is being set up when running the node. Because the node needs chromedriver, so chromedriver must be stored on the node and accessed when running the node

Comment: driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://10.0.11.118:5566/wd/hub"), capabilities); //i check in debug in my mac, it throw error on this line

Comment: can we talk over chat please

Comment: Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: The path to the driver executable must be set by the webdriver.chrome.driver system property; for more information, see http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/ChromeDriver. The latest version can be downloaded from http://code.google.com/p/chromedriver/downloads/list
Command duration or timeout: 654 milliseconds

Again same error, tireddddd

Comment: we cannot, since you do not have enough reputation for that. See yet another edit.

Answer (score 0):

Start the hub in Mac with below command

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.33.0.jar -role hub
```

Start the node in windows with below command

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.33.0.jar -role node -hub http://localhost:4444/grid/register -maxSession 15 -browser browserName="chrome",version=ANY,platform=WINDOWS,maxInstances=15 -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=pathtochromedriver\chromedriver.exe
```

Download chromedriver from below location

https://code.google.com/p/chromedriver/downloads/list

Now intialize driver instance with below logic

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/Users/test/chromedriver");
DesiredCapabilities dc=new DesiredCapabilities();
dc.setBrowserName("chrome");
dc.setPlatform(Platform.WINDOWS);
driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://localhost:4444/wd/hub"), dc);
driver.get(Constants.SERVER_URL_NAME);
```

Comment: I have stated hub and node both as u above said and written logic in mac machine same as above but still getting an error. 

I have download chrome driver for both windows and mac.
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/Users/test/chromedriver"); --here i am need to provide chrome driver path of mac right?

Comment: You need to start node in windows machine not in mac. Download chromedriver in windows machine and start node from windows machine as I mentioned.