# How to run chrome browser in grid using windows as hub and mac and ipad as nodes?

Tags: ios, .net, macos, selenium, appium

Hub: Windows 64-bit  Nod: Mac/Ipad

I'm looking to automate chrome browser in mac and ipad  and add to our selenium grid running on windows, c# scripts.  Please advise.  And also if appium is required and does it have to run the server on a mac for the ios testing?

*I'm modeling my question after the link below as clearly others have been able to convey the question just fine, yet every time I've asked I've been flagged as not asking properly, and now there's a notice threatening to block me? Mystified as to why I'm receiving different treatment, please explain how this is not clear and allow for commenting.  Isn't that what comments are for anyways?

*update due to lack of comment status*
Please note my follow up question on Appium with a narrower scope: is appium is required and does it have to run the server on a mac for the ios testing? Y/N- That doesn't get any narrower.  Plus I can't run code and get errors without having the correct tools setup.  Otherwise there is little documentation available on this out there, and what there is is either not great or older, and all are running java code on the mac which is not the .net windows setup we have. Even though the rules may have changed, clearly breadth isn't an issue as people seem to understood other broad questions just fine. I've done several days of research on this.

[How to run chrome browser in grid using MAC as hub and Windows as Nod?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17550687/how-to-run-chrome-browser-in-grid-using-mac-as-hub-and-windows-as-nod)

**Obviously this has been hashed before
 [Why is Stack Overflow so negative of late?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251758/why-is-stack-overflow-so-negative-of-late).  I would add downvoting and not answering questions no matter how noob kinda goes against the very core mission answer sites have--answering questions.  If this site won't, some other site will.

Comment: Your question is way too broad and doesn't show any research. The question you linked is from 2013 and the rules were different back then. Do some research and try to accomplish what you are asking. If you run into an issue, research that specific issue and see if you can overcome it. If you can't, come back and ask a question around that specific issue with supporting information, research, code, samples, etc. and we can help you. As it current stands, your question will get closed for being too broad.

Answer (score 0):

Let me try to Answer your Questions one by one :

- `I'm looking to automate chrome browser in mac and ipad and add to our selenium grid running on windows, c# scripts. Please advise.` : Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, [describe the problem](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254393/what-exactly-is-a-recommendation-question) and what has been done so far to solve it.
- `If appium is required and does it have to run the server on a mac for the ios testing` : Automating `Web Application` requires only `Selenium`. If you are automating `Mobile Application` you have to go with **`Appium`**.
- `Every time I've asked I've been flagged as not asking properly, and now there's a notice threatening to block me? Mystified as to why I'm receiving different treatment` : Answer is same as @JeffC mentioned in his comment **`Your question is way too broad and doesn't show any research. The question you linked is from 2013 and the rules were different back then. Do some research and try to accomplish what you are asking. If you run into an issue, research that specific issue and see if you can overcome it. If you can't, come back and ask a question around that specific issue with supporting information, research, code, samples, etc. and we can help you. As it current stands, your question will get closed for being too broad.`**
- `Is appium is required and does it have to run the server on a mac for the ios testing?` : **Appium** is required and you can run it on your `Desktop`/`Local Systsem` as well.
- `I can't run code and get errors without having the correct tools setup` : Every `Automation Engineer` starts with a similar situation. So you are on the right track.
- `There is little documentation available on this out there, and what there is is either not great or older` : Help us (stackoverflow.com) to prepare more documentation.
- `I've done several days of research on this How to run chrome browser in grid using MAC as hub and Windows as Nod?` : The question was raised as early as **Jul 9 '13 at 14:19**. Almost half a decade back. By now you should have made your hands dirty with **Hard Disk full of Code**
- `Obviously this has been hashed before Why is Stack Overflow so negative of late?` : If you have any concern feel free to raise it at [**`StackOverflow - Meta`**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/)

### Solution

It is never late to start anything new. Start writing your code. Get your fingers dirty. Feel free to raise any Technical Question where you get stuck. StackOverflow volunteers will be happy to help you out.

Comment: Thank you for answering one question. Right now I'm focusing on simply registering a node.  There's not much code to this this one task of connecting mac node to hub, simply configuration, and the log file will reflect that. I never asked How to run chrome browser in grid using MAC as hub and Windows as Nod?  That was someone else.  They got an answer without posting their hub/node configuration.  I can post c# capabilities too, but I know it won't work until I have a node registered.

Comment: Great News !!! Please **`Accept`** the **`Answer`** by clicking on the tick mark beside my **`Answer`** which is just below `VoteDown` arrow, so the tick mark turns **`Green`** and raise a `New Question` with your new requirement. Changing the `Question` after you receive an `Answer` is against the `StackOverflow` standards. Please revert back the Question changes for the benefit of future readers. Thanks

Comment: I would love to help with documentation, but I can't do that if I'm downvoted and blocked.  That creates an atmosphere of frustration and people aren't going to want to help a site that does that.

Comment: I don't know someone answered when I changed it.  It simply a refresh issue.  Again frustration goes both ways.

Comment: I have rolled back your Question change please accept the Answer.